# Office.js content add-in insertion behavior

Tags: office-js

When I installed an Office.js content add-in in Excel/PowerPoint before 4 October 2017, it automatically added an "insert button" to the Insert tab on the ribbon. If I pressed this button, the content add-in itself is inserted to the current document. However on 4 October 2017 this behavior suddenly changed and when I now install a content add-in, the "Add" button on the install screen immediately inserts the content add-in itself into the document, without creating its own button on the ribbon.

Our content add-in's manifest is almost the same as the original manifest that is generated by Visual Studio and it does not matter whether the content add-in is installed from Office Store or a local shared folder. This phenomenon also affects our older product releases as well as other third party content add-ins.

My current Office version is Version 1708 (Build 8431.2094), but I don't think it is an Office version-related issue as I rolled back to a previous version before 4 October, but it didn't help at all.

I know that content add-ins can also be chosen from the "My Add-ins" dropdown list from Add-ins group on Insert tab, but that would be a step back in UX compared to a dedicated insert button on the ribbon.

Is it an intended new behavior of inserting content add-ins or is this a bug? Can this feature be controlled by developers? Is there any way to get our insert button back? Is there any way to put an "insert content add-in button" to a custom tab that is defined for task panes?

**UPDATE:**

Here is the manifest we use for the content add-in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
          xsi:type="ContentApp">

  <Id>xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Xxxxxxxxxx</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Insert stuff" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Insert stuff to current document"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://xxxxxxx/icon.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="http://xxxxxxxx" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>http://localhost:12345</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Presentation" />
    <Host Name="Workbook" />
  </Hosts>
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost:12345/path/to/index.html" />
    <RequestedWidth>400</RequestedWidth>
    <RequestedHeight>440</RequestedHeight>
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Could you share your manifest (with names, urls and ids redacted to protect the innocent)?

Comment: @Marc I updated with the manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ribbon button for content add-ins was an experimental feature that we enabled temporarily for a subset of users. We're now reviewing the data from the experiment and will decide how to improve the behaviour of content add-ins on the ribbon in the future (we may decide to officially ship something similar to what we shipped in the experiment). Thanks for your feedback, and sorry for taking away something that you liked!

-Michael (program manager for add-ins)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how do we know if a particular computer belongs to a subset of users who have experimental features and exactly what experimental features they have? This was present for my dev team as well as for our customer. But our customer resides in a different geolocation than us developers, bought his machine there and uses the Office shipped with it,while some of us developers have reinstalled our machines relative recently and some of us use same Office for a longer period, but seemingly independent of everything we all experienced this experimental feature.

Comment: It is about predictability and substitutability,not about the liking of a feature.Unfortunately we didn't know that this was an experimental feature and our customer expected this button to stay because MS's preference of buttons on the ribbon or until a potential better solution arrives (content add-ins and task panes can be placed next to each other,onto a separate custom tab) as this insert button at least made UX somewhat acceptable for content add-ins. [importance of ribbon](https://www.pcworld.com/article/3050320/software/microsoft-will-let-you-run-custom-apps-from-office-ribbons.html)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback here. It sounds like you'd prefer more information about experiments that we will be running and also that you'd prefer having content add-ins appear on the ribbon. (By the way, task pane buttons and code-execution buttons can both be configured to appear on the ribbon, officially. It's only content add-ins that don't have this capability yet).