# Can an Office.js content add-in be inserted programmatically?

Tags: office-js

I have an Office.js application which consists of one taskpane add-in, multiple corresponding content add-ins and function file commands.

- What are the different ways of inserting a content add-in into a document, [now that the "insert content add-in button" is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608734/office-js-content-add-in-insertion-behavior#46719939)? I know that a content add-in, by default, can be inserted from the ribbon, choosing Insert --> My Add-ins and browsing my content add-in, but it is not a user-friendly task to do and I am looking for something neater, customizable solution.
- Is there any way to insert a content add-in programmatically (considering security) or it always requires a *manual* interaction from the user through the ribbon? It would be great to insert a content add-in directly from the corresponding Taskpane, for example by pressing a button there. Is this possible? If not then can you please suggest any other method for inserting a content add-in other than the previously mentioned "default" one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid they can only be inserted via My Add-ins. There has certainly been feedback around the user experience (or lack there of) that this imposes.

I recommend visiting the [UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and adding this suggestion.

Comment: Hi Marc, do you know if there's been any update on this since 2017? I'm not finding anything online, but hopefully that's just because of my searching skills

Comment: I don't believe so.